# How do I change the png images? Github Yalantis Library?

Tags: java, android, shared-libraries

I recently found this great git online from Yalantis, its called Phoenix Pull-to-Refresh and in the description, it says that 
sun png SunImage
sky png background image
buildings png foreground image
I already compiled the dependencies and implemented the Pull-To-Refresh
My Question is how do I change the png images?

```
    mPullToRefreshView = (PullToRefreshView)view.findViewById(R.id.pull_to_refresh);
    mPullToRefreshView.setOnRefreshListener(new PullToRefreshView.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            mPullToRefreshView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mPullToRefreshView.setRefreshing(false);
                    JsonRequestMethod();
                }
            }, REFRESH_DELAY);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Comment: define a sun.png image in your project, it will override the resource from the library.

Comment: So do i just add a drawable called sun.png to an xml file?? Or do I need to do it via java

Comment: `to an xml file?` what xml file? no, just have a damn sun.png file in your drawables.

Comment: i have a damn sun.png file in my drawable folder but it doesn't work